# Searching Natural Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ are natural numbers satisfying the following

$~1\leq a$,$b$,$c$,$d\leq 9$.
$a+b+c\equiv 1$ (mod $d$)
$a+c+d\equiv 1$ (mod $b$)
$a+b+d\equiv 1$ (mod $c$)
$b+c+d\equiv 1$ (mod $a$)

Find $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$

Answer (score 2):

Because of the symmetry, we may as well demand that $a \le b \le c \le d$  Do you allow $1 \pmod 1?$.  If we do allow it, I find the following solutions:
$$1 1 1 1\\
1 1 1 2\\
1 1 2 3\\
1 2 2 2\\
1 2 2 4\\
1 2 4 6\\
1 3 3 3\\
1 3 3 6\\
1 3 6 9\\
1 4 4 4\\
1 4 4 8\\
1 5 5 5\\
1 6 6 6\\
1 7 7 7\\
1 8 8 8\\
1 9 9 9\\
2 2 2 5\\
2 2 3 6\\
2 2 6 9\\
2 3 4 4\\
3 3 3 4\\
3 3 5 5\\
3 6 8 8$$ but don't see a neat way to find them except brute force.